# JavaScript - x3 Drop Down Selection Not Working

Tags: javascript

I have 3 drop downs (selctors) the choice of each one reveals the next. Im having issues though with the initial menus disappearing, and more than 3 being present at once. Here's the code:

I'm new to coding, any help would be greatly appreciated!
Cheers

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>

<style>

p {
font-size:2.5vw;
font-family:arial;
}

select {
width:auto;
margin:0;
font-size:2.5vw;
font-family:arial;
}

.inv {
display: none;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<select id="target">
<option value="">First</option>
<option value="option100">100</option>
<option value="option200">200</option>
<select>




<select id="option100" class="inv">
<option value="">Second</option>
<option value="option110">110</option>
<option value="option120">120</option>
<select>

<select id="option200" class="inv">
<option value="">Second</option>
<option value="option210">210</option>
<option value="option220">220</option>
<select>




<select id="option110" class="inv">
<option value="">Third</option>
<option value="option111">111</option>
<option value="option112">112</option>
<select>

<select id="option120" class="inv">
<option value="">Third</option>
<option value="option121">121</option>
<option value="option122">122</option>
<select>

<select id="option210" class="inv">
<option value="">Third</option>
<option value="option211">211</option>
<option value="option212">212</option>
<select>

<select id="option220" class="inv">
<option value="">Third</option>
<option value="option221">221</option>
<option value="option222">222</option>
<select>


<script>

document
.getElementById('target')
.addEventListener('change', function () {'use strict';
var vis = document.querySelector('.vis'),   
target = document.getElementById(this.value);
if (vis !== null) {
vis.className = 'inv';
}
if (target !== null ) {
target.className = 'vis';
}
});

document
.getElementById('option100')
.addEventListener('change', function () {'use strict';
var vis = document.querySelector('.vis'),   
target = document.getElementById(this.value);
if (vis !== null) {
vis.className = 'inv';
}
if (target !== null ) {
target.className = 'vis';
}
});

document
.getElementById('option200')
.addEventListener('change', function () {'use strict';
var vis = document.querySelector('.vis'),   
target = document.getElementById(this.value);
if (vis !== null) {
vis.className = 'inv';
}
if (target !== null ) {
target.className = 'vis';
}
});

document
.getElementById('option110')
.addEventListener('change', function () {'use strict';
var vis = document.querySelector('.vis'),   
target = document.getElementById(this.value);
if (vis !== null) {
vis.className = 'inv';
}
if (target !== null ) {
target.className = 'vis';
}
});

document
.getElementById('option120')
.addEventListener('change', function () {'use strict';
var vis = document.querySelector('.vis'),   
target = document.getElementById(this.value);
if (vis !== null) {
vis.className = 'inv';
}
if (target !== null ) {
target.className = 'vis';
}
});

document
.getElementById('option210')
.addEventListener('change', function () {'use strict';
var vis = document.querySelector('.vis'),   
target = document.getElementById(this.value);
if (vis !== null) {
vis.className = 'inv';
}
if (target !== null ) {
target.className = 'vis';
}
});

document
.getElementById('option220')
.addEventListener('change', function () {'use strict';
var vis = document.querySelector('.vis'),   
target = document.getElementById(this.value);
if (vis !== null) {
vis.className = 'inv';
}
if (target !== null ) {
target.className = 'vis';
}
});

document
.getElementById('option111')
.addEventListener('change', function () {'use strict';
var vis = document.querySelector('.vis'),   
target = document.getElementById(this.value);
if (vis !== null) {
vis.className = 'inv';
}
if (target !== null ) {
target.className = 'vis';
}
});

document
.getElementById('option112')
.addEventListener('change', function () {'use strict';
var vis = document.querySelector('.vis'),   
target = document.getElementById(this.value);
if (vis !== null) {
vis.className = 'inv';
}
if (target !== null ) {
target.className = 'vis';
}
});

document
.getElementById('option121')
.addEventListener('change', function () {'use strict';
var vis = document.querySelector('.vis'),   
target = document.getElementById(this.value);
if (vis !== null) {
vis.className = 'inv';
}
if (target !== null ) {
target.className = 'vis';
}
});

document
.getElementById('option122')
.addEventListener('change', function () {'use strict';
var vis = document.querySelector('.vis'),   
target = document.getElementById(this.value);
if (vis !== null) {
vis.className = 'inv';
}
if (target !== null ) {
target.className = 'vis';
}
});

document
.getElementById('option211')
.addEventListener('change', function () {'use strict';
var vis = document.querySelector('.vis'),   
target = document.getElementById(this.value);
if (vis !== null) {
vis.className = 'inv';
}
if (target !== null ) {
target.className = 'vis';
}
});

document
.getElementById('option212')
.addEventListener('change', function () {'use strict';
var vis = document.querySelector('.vis'),   
target = document.getElementById(this.value);
if (vis !== null) {
vis.className = 'inv';
}
if (target !== null ) {
target.className = 'vis';
}
});

document
.getElementById('option221')
.addEventListener('change', function () {'use strict';
var vis = document.querySelector('.vis'),   
target = document.getElementById(this.value);
if (vis !== null) {
vis.className = 'inv';
}
if (target !== null ) {
target.className = 'vis';
}
});

document
.getElementById('option222')
.addEventListener('change', function () {'use strict';
var vis = document.querySelector('.vis'),   
target = document.getElementById(this.value);
if (vis !== null) {
vis.className = 'inv';
}
if (target !== null ) {
target.className = 'vis';
}
});

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not solve the intended problem. But here are some pointers.

-You are not closing the `select` elements. make sure you include a closing tag.

```
<select id="target">
   <option value="">First</option>
   <option value="option100">100</option>
   <option value="option200">200</option>
</select>
```

-Also you seem to be binding events for each element and the code inside each block is exactly the same. Instead bind the events to the tagNames or a specific class so as to avoid duplication.

```
var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
    selects[i].addEventListener('change', function () {
        'use strict';
        var vis = document.querySelector('.vis'),
            target = document.getElementById(this.value);
        if (vis !== null) {
            for (var j = 0; j < vis.length; j++) {
                vis[j].className = 'inv';
            }

        }
        if (target !== null) {
            target.className = 'vis';
        }
    });
};
```

In this block of code

```
var vis = document.querySelector('.vis');
```

// returns more than 1 element as you are querying it by class name. So it should look like below.

```
var vis = document.querySelector('.vis'),
    target = document.getElementById(this.value);
    if (vis !== null) {
       for (var j = 0; j < vis.length; j++) {
          vis[j].className = 'inv';
       }
    }
```